# Animating two paths between onDraw callbacks

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have a triangle path which I wanted to draw over a `Canvas` , after five seconds I'm redrawing this path on `onDraw()` callback function . but it's jumpy and i want that to be animated smoothly, I've searched a lot but I've found such this link which animate path through five seconds not at the edge of time :

How to animate a path on canvas - android

I can animate drawing that path between those five seconds but its not my need , I need to animate the redrawn path exactly when five seconds elapsed then translate first path to second path . any help would be appreciated